# Audio detection in an embedded system

Tags: c++, c, audio, embedded

I'm getting started with embedded, and was thinking to start learning by implementing some sort of a clapper project where I detect audio and respond to it.

I have some specific questions, but since I'm new to this field, please add any additional advice

- What audio libraries exist that could help with this type of project
- What hardware do I need to actually detect the sound waves
- I was considering an Arduino? Is this a good choice for this type of project?
- I still haven't decided on the language (c or c++) but it will be influenced by the libraries available and the chip I use

Answer (score 3):

The [arduino](http://www.arduino.cc/) is a good entry point here. I see that there is already an arduino project [using sound to trigger a digital camera](http://blog.glocal.ca/2008/06/17/digital-camera-hack/) which should answer most of your questions concerning libraries and hardware requirements - they have a [download](http://www.glocal.ca/downloads/glocal_camera_trigger_june26_08.zip) with circuit diagrams and arduino source code.

Answer (score 0):

For hardware, you typically want a microphone (or an audio input jack), with some amplifier and analog filter circuitry, connected to an analog input pin on a microcontroller.

You will need some driver software in the microcontroller to read input samples from the analog input.